# Why are NextApiRequestCookies, parseBody from NextJS in 'next/dist/server/api-utils'

Tags: next.js

In NextJS I'm pulling `NextApiRequestCookies` (TypeScript type) and `parseBody` (method) out of `'next/dist/server/api-utils'` - this works but it feels wrong to be using them from there and on top of that parseBody doesn't seem to be documented on the official site.

Why are these undocumented methods here and not exported from 'next'?

Comment: I'd guess because those are used internally by Next.js and not meant to be used by its consumers. Out of curiosity, why are you using those?

Comment: I want to do a POST against a page and not an API endpoint and use this functionality.